# How can I let NetworkManager connect to Ethernet when I'm not logged in?

Tags: networkmanager

I've a Intel NUC6i3SYH running Debian GNU/Linux Unstable. It's connected to the internet through Ethernet. I'm using NetworkManager, but it only connects to the internet when I'm logged in. How can I set up NetworkManager so that it connects to the internet even when I'm not logged in (so that I could remotely SSH into it)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `connection.permissions` which restricts the profile to a user.

`nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" connection.permissions ""`

Or use the GUI to configure the profile in a similar manner .